# My App is not working n samsung galaxy ace duos

Tags: android, version, coronasdk

I have made a Game using CORONA SDK, and during Building I set Andorind Version as 2.2 And Above, but when i tried to install that Game on Galaxy Ace Duos, It shows Error in installation due to Version Incompatibility. I searched & found that Samsung Ace Duos has Android 2.3.6. So according to that App should Worked. 
What to do!!

Comment: can you post a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the CPU on it is not of the ARMv7 family or later processors.  It looks like an ARM9 which is of the ARMv3 family and Corona SDK is not compatible with.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to launch the application on the SDK first to see if it works. I would suggest you to use Eclipse instead of Corona. If problem still persist, try switching it to your phone's version and try it out to see if the problem still occurs.

Cheers.